# Only install packages that are included in the package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, package-managers

I just want to install only packages that are included in the packages.json. But when I run **npm install**, over 800 packages are suddenly installed. Is there a specific command to realize this or is my package.json (see below) wrong?

```
    {
      "name": "test",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "test",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "test",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
        "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
        "gulp-htmlmin": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
        "gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-jade": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-jsonminify": "^1.0.0",
        "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "critical": "^1.2.2",
        "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.0"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case when u install this packages the dependencies of that particular packages has also been installed.

Like if u install **critical** module then =>
bluebird
chalk
cheerio
clean-css
cli
debug
filter-css
fs-extra ... etc
has also been installed, that's the case in here

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` uses package.json to install packages you want **AND** their own dependencies. So you haven't choice unless you want broken packages ? In that case you could manually uninstall packages you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would that be happening, whenever we run npm install it picks up the package.json and installs packages defined in it including the transitive dependencies. By looking at your package.json there should not be 800 of them.unless you have multiple package.json linked up with each other.
I would recommend to copy package.json to a different directory and clear cached in modules and

> run npm install --log-level=verbose
>   this should give in the details for the rest packages being called up.

Comment: npm install --log-level=verbose gives me: 
npm WARN official_portfolio@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 6.112s

Comment: Bear in mind that NPM v3 and above [installs dependencies of dependencies in `node_modules` rather than nesting them to avoid file path length limits](http://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/npm3/how-npm3-works.html). 800 folders in there doesn't sound unreasonable to me.

Comment: So is it right that suddenly so many packages are there? I have the latest node version.

Comment: try npm install --loglevel=verbose or npm install --verbose

Comment: @Codehan25: For comparison, the project I'm currently working on has 45 dependencies/dev-dependencies - my `node_modules` folder contains 1070 packages.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Thanks to all :)